# Facing issue in writing Nested Dictionaries to Newly Created SQL Table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write the nested dictionaries in the newly created SQL Table.

I think I have made some mistake in creating new table in SQL by mentioning its column also. Could anyone please review the code & tell me whether this step is correct or not.

```
db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    database = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00"
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Details ( User_ID VARCHAR(255), Name VARCHAR(255), Age VARCHAR(255) ) ")
```

I need to write a nested Python dictionary into a SQL table. I'm trying to do it by using a for loop.
This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
user_details = {}
create_user_ID = input(" Enter the user ID :  ")
user_details[create_user_ID] = {}
user_name = input(" Enter the user name : ")
user_details[create_user_ID]['Name'] = user_name
user_age = int(input(" Enter the Age : "))
user_details[create_user_ID]['Age'] = user_age

for v in user_details.values():
    cols = v.keys()
    vals = v.values()

    sql = "INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
        ', '.join(cols),
        ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));

    cursor.execute(sql, vals)
```

If I run this code I'm getting the following error

```
Error : Couldn't process parameters
```

Could anyone please review the code and tell me where I've made the mistake, whether in creating SQL Table or in FOR Loop.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is when you try to create sql query inside the loop.try this one

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Details {}) VALUES ({})".format(
    ', '.join(cols),
    ', '.join(map(str,vals)));
```